# Does not wearing a coat when it's "cold" out make you sick?

Tags: medical-science, physiology, common-cold

I live in Maryland, where today it was about 50°F. I have heard this before, but my parents told me to wear my coat outside at school because the cold would "make me sick." Is it really true that being cold gives you a cold?

Comment: The body might be more vulnerable when harsh weather conditions are applied allowing a opening for a Viruses,bacteria,parasites,fungus,spores or other microbes to enter the blood system.Temperature does not create the  Viruses,bacteria,parasites,fungus,spores or other microbes.